J. J. Thomson's "on momentum in the electric field": can it be true physically?
J. J. Thomson imagined a physical system consisting of one electric field source (charge $q$ or else) and one magnetic field source (magnetic monopole $g$ or maybe magnet or something else), with $q$ and $g$ apart from each other with distance $d$ between them. Then he derived the vector $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{E} \times \mathbf{B}$. But it is not physically consistent as according to Maxwell's equations and physical observations, totally independent apart $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ sources can not establish $\mathbf{S}$ vector. So is it physically correct?
“It doesn’t matter how beautiful your theory is, it doesn’t matter how smart you are. If it doesn’t agree with experiment, it’s wrong.”
Richard P. Feynman
J. J. Thomson. On momentum in the electric field, Philos. Mag. Volume 8, pp. 331-356, (1904).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The theory does agree with experiment, except for its predictions of the resulting gravitational field which are far beyond experimental accessibility. Also I would not call it 'physically inconsistent'. It does go against intuition, as is most clearly expressed by the late, great Feynman in his lectures, volume 2, chapter 27.5. In the tapes he calls the theory nuts, intuitively screwy and crazy but then concludes with

You no doubt begin to get the impression that the Poynting theory at least partially violates your intuition as to where energy is located in an electromagnetic field. You might believe that you must revamp all your intuitions, and, therefore have a lot of things to study here. But it seems really not necessary. You don’t need to feel that you will be in great trouble if you forget once in a while that the energy in a wire is flowing into the wire from the outside, rather than along the wire. It seems to be only rarely of value, when using the idea of energy conservation, to notice in detail what path the energy is taking. The circulation of energy around a magnet and a charge seems, in most circumstances, to be quite unimportant. It is not a vital detail, but it is clear that our ordinary intuitions are quite wrong.

Take a look at my paper, Eur. Phys. J. D, vol. 8, p 9-12 (2000), which solves the issue.
